Troubleshooting 401 errors && ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB on LightningOut using a custom domain
We're attempting to use a custom domain (ex. https://lightningout.example.com) to as the domain for lightning out components, see example below. We've configured a subdomain on our website and issues a specific CA-cert for that subdomain, the HTTPS site is loading with no issues and we've linked the subdomain to an experience site that loads with no issue.
The problem arises when we are attempting to use that subdomain within $lightning.use()
<!-- Lightning Out -->
<script src="https://lightningout.example.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
<div id="lightningoutwidget" style="z-index: 999;position: absolute;"></div>

<script>
$Lightning.use(
  'namespace:lightningApp', // name of the Lightning app
  function () {
    // Callback once framework and app loaded
    $Lightning.createComponent(
      'namespace:lightningComponent', // Component
      {
        view: 'button',
        showFilters: true,
        notificationsEnabled: true, 
        notificationMessage: '',
      }, // attributes to set on the component when created
      'lightningoutwidget', // the DOM location to insert the component
      function (cmp) {
        console.log('component created');
        // callback when component is created and active on the page
      }
    );
  },
  'https://lightningout.example.com', // Site endpoint
  {{{access_token}}}
);

</script>

Our lightning app and lighting component are configured to not allow guest user access and we do not want to give guest user access. Additionally that {{{access_token}}} variable is from a system admin.
We're follow step #4 on this link :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/lightning-out-third-party-cookies.html

Hello Did you get an answer to this question. We started getting (failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB uses on preview orgs for Summer'24 in one of the network calls that uses URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() to derive the URL for downloading an image file
